# Set a getter into a firestore section of vuefire

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

Am looking for a way of setting an a property from getters to the firestore section with vue. Am using vuefire , but am getting this error :

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToUid' of undefined

below is my code :

```
    data: () => ({
      name:'',
    }),
    firestore: () => ({
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        usersList: db.collection(users),
        dmMessages: db.collection(direct_message).doc(this.getToUid).collection(message_collection_name)
      }),
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
          getToUid: "chats/GET_TO_UID",
        }),
    }
```

What could be the best way of setting the `getToUid` into this line :

```
 dmMessages: db.collection(direct_message).doc(this.getToUid).collection(message_collection_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `firestore` option should not be an arrow function or it can't access the component instance through `this`.  Change it to:

```js
firestore() {
  return {
    usersList: db.collection(users),
    dmMessages: db.collection(direct_message).doc(this.getToUid).collection(message_collection_name)
  }
},
```